# Prove that $(I-ix)^{-1}(I+ix)(I-ix)(I+ix)^{-1} = I$

Tags: matrices

I have a question

> Prove $$(I-ix)^{-1}(I+ix)(I-ix)(I+ix)^{-1} = I$$

with $x$ being a $n \times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$(I+ix)(I-ix) = I + x^2 = (I-ix)(I+ix)$$
Now you are done.